# is my model using future data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a model in TensorFlow to predict a time series. The network gets a window of data of length L and tries to come up with the next value.

I do the training in batches of overlapping windows (that slide forward in time). To speed up the process, instead of feeding an array of windows, I feed a single larger one and I use `tf.extract_image_patches` to extract the windows.

My question is: is it the case that the model can "cheat" by looking at the next values in the larger window? Technically, the next value of each window (except for the last one) is in the initial large window that I feed at the beginning.

EDIT: my model is a custom recurrent neural network, that is fed the various windows (one per loop) and the previous prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using `Recurrent units`, your model wouldn't know what it is going to be fed next.

Also, it is generally not a good idea to keep such a structure (overlapping windows) in input data. It's better to use shuffled data, rest whatever works in your particular case.

Comment: Ah, yes, I am using a recurrent network, which at each step is fed a window and the previous prediction. That's why for the moment I need the windows in a batch to be overlapping (the batches themselves are taken from random positions in the time series). So in this case my model is cheating?